Shrink a grid shape according to the shape of a curve
Assuming there is a grid shape with its lower half shrinking according to the shape of the curve, is there a tool in Blender that can achieve a similar function.

The outside transparent object is the origin object, it seems that the shrinking part will not exceed the range of the original object.
